# Drawing heatmap for a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, heatmap

I want to draw a heatmap corresponding to a matrix in R. I am using the following command:

```
heatmap(my_heatmap, Rowv=NA, Colv=NA, col = cm.colors(256), scale="column", margins=c(10,10))
```

The problem is that `heatmap` command seems like to produce the heatmap for each column separately and does not consider the whole matrix. Any idea for that?

Comment: The first example in the `?heatmap` help works just fine for me. What does your matrix look like?

Comment: Color me `darkpuzzled`. You have not described what you want or why you used `scale="column"` if that is not what you wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've explicitly set `scale="column"` which rescales the data for each column. If that's not what you want, try `scale="none"`.